# How can I get a (String) value from flow in Apex controller?

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, string

I have a flow: There is a String value in one of fields in my flow and I have to take this value and do some computations with that value and return some records based on that String in a "second part" of flow.

I have a Visualforce page with this code:

```
<apex:page tabStyle="Opportunity" controller="CLocationRequestController" id="page">
<apex:sectionHeader title="Request to add a new Location"/>
 <flow:interview name="Location_Request" buttonLocation="bottom" allowShowPause="true" showHelp="true" finishLocation="{!returnPage}">
    <apex:param name="OppId" value="{!oppId}"/>
 </flow:interview>
</apex:page>
```

How can I get a value from flow to Apex code?

Answer (score 1):

Create a reference to a [Flow.Interview](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/flow_interview_class.htm), then you can call getVariableName to retrieve the value of a variable from the flow during the process.

```
<flow:interview interview="{!interview}" name="Location_Request" buttonLocation="bottom" allowShowPause="true" showHelp="true" finishLocation="{!returnPage}">
```

...

```
public Flow.Interview.Location_Request interview { get; set; }
```